# `mysqli_insert_id` PHP Class

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a social site and I give people the option to upload one or more posts. That part works fine.

My problem is if someone uploads a post without pictures, then it gets submitted to a function and everything is fine. But if someone submits a post with pictures the only thing that's wrong is, I can't get the `id` of the post so I can put it in one of the columns for the image(s).

I know what the problem is. When I try to use procedural programming to upload the post and images, I get the id and everything is fine. But when I use OOP to upload the post and then try to get the id it doesn't work. No errors or anything the value in the column just comes out to `0`. Can someone help me please ?

```
$post = new Post($con, $userLoggedIn);

$title = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['title_post'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )));
$body = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['post_text'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )));
$post->submitPost($title, $body, 'none', $imageName);

if (!$errors) {

        $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO post_images (image, post_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $file_path, $id);

        // Loop through each file
        for( $i=0; $i < $file_count; $i++ ) {

            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            if ($file_size >= $maxsize) {

                $errors = "Your file is too large";

            } elseif ($imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "jpg" && 
                $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "gif") {

                $errors = "File type not allowed.";
            }
            //Make sure we have a file path
            if (!$errors /* && $file_tmp != "" */) {

                $picToUpload = $date_time . " -#- " . md5($file_name) . " -#- " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $uploadPicture = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads/" . $picToUpload);

                $file_path = "uploads/" . $picToUpload;
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Post.php:

```
public function submitPost($title, $body, $user_to, $imageName) {

        $title = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['title_post'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
        $body = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($body, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
        $check_empty = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $body); //Deletes all spaces
        $check_empty_title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $title); //Deletes all spaces 
      
        if($check_empty != "" || $check_empty_title != "" || $imageName != "") {

            $body_array = preg_split("/\s+/", $body);
            $title_array = preg_split("/\s+/", $title);

            $body = implode(" ", $body_array);
            $title = implode(" ", $title_array);
            //Current date and time
            $date_added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            //Get username
            $added_by = $this->user_obj->getUsername();

            //If user is on own profile, user_to is 'none'
            if($user_to == $added_by) {
                $user_to = "none";
            }

            //insert post 
            $query = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, body, added_by, user_to, image) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $query->bind_param("sssss", $title, $body, $added_by, $user_to, $imageName);
            $query->execute();
            $returned_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->con);

            //Insert notification 

            if($user_to != 'none') {

                $notification = new Notification($this->con, $added_by);
                $notification->insertNotification($returned_id, $user_to, "profile_post");
            }

            //Update post count for user 
            $num_posts = $this->user_obj->getNumPosts();
            $num_posts++;

            $update_query = $this->con->prepare('UPDATE users SET num_posts = ? WHERE username = ?');
            $update_query->bind_param("is", $num_posts, $added_by );
            $update_query->execute();

            $stopWords = "i you are gay am a about above brandon tisson";

            $stopWords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $stopWords);

            $no_punctuation = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9] +/", "", $body);

            if (strpos($no_punctuation, "height") === false && strpos($no_punctuation, "width") 
                === false && strpos($no_punctuation, "http") === false) {

                $no_punctuation = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $no_punctuation);

                foreach ($stopWords as $value ) {

                    foreach ($no_punctuation as $key => $value2) {

                        if (strtolower($value) == strtolower($value2) ) {

                            $no_punctuation[$key] = "";
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach ($no_punctuation as $value) {

                    $this->calculateTrend(ucfirst($value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So in conclusion I'm trying to get the id of the post from a function in procedure style code.

Comment: You can `return $returned_id` from `submitPost()`, and then use that the code that adds the images.

Comment: @Barmar say that again ?

Comment: Procedural and OOP mysqli are equivalent.

Comment: Do `return $returned_id;` at the end of `submitPost()`, and then use `$id = $post->submitPost($title, $body, 'none', $imageName);` to get it.

Comment: If you want to use OOP, use `$query->insert_id`.

Comment: Or `$con->insert_id`

Comment: It was that simple. Wow. Thanks. Do you want to put it as an answer ?

Comment: What does `insertNotification` do? If it also does an `INSERT`, then when you call `mysqli_insert_id($con)` in the caller, you're getting that ID, not the post ID.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's the same ID. I have this in another project but I'm building a new one. When I try it in the other one I think everything is fine.

Comment: If it were the same ID, you wouldn't be having a problem.

Comment: Is `$con` in the main script the same as `$this->con` in the class? The last insert ID is specific to a particular connection.

Comment: Never mind, I just saw `new Post($con, $userLoggedIn)`, so they're obviously the same.

Comment: Now I have another problem my post gets submitted twice @Barmar

Comment: That's not due to the code here, it's a problem in your client application.

Comment: Yeah nevermind I fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the post ID from `submitPost()`. Otherwise, if there are other inserts (such as in `$notification->insertNotification()`) they'll overwrite the ID returned by `mysqli_insert_id($con)`.

It's also a little better to use `$query->insert_id` rather than `mysqli_insert_id($this->con);` since it's specific to that `INSERT` query, rather than the most recent `INSERT` on the same connection.

```
$post = new Post($con, $userLoggedIn);

$title = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['title_post'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )));
$body = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['post_text'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )));
$id = $post->submitPost($title, $body, 'none', $imageName);

if (!$errors) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO post_images (image, post_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $file_path, $id);

    // Loop through each file
    for( $i=0; $i < $file_count; $i++ ) {

        $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        if ($file_size >= $maxsize) {
            $errors = "Your file is too large";
        } elseif ($imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "jpg" && 
                  $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
            $errors = "File type not allowed.";
        }
        //Make sure we have a file path
        if (!$errors /* && $file_tmp != "" */) {
            $picToUpload = $date_time . " -#- " . md5($file_name) . " -#- " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $uploadPicture = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads/" . $picToUpload);
            $file_path = "uploads/" . $picToUpload;
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public function submitPost($title, $body, $user_to, $imageName) {
    $title = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['title_post'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $body = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($body, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $check_empty = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $body); //Deletes all spaces
    $check_empty_title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $title); //Deletes all spaces 
      
    if($check_empty != "" || $check_empty_title != "" || $imageName != "") {
        $body_array = preg_split("/\s+/", $body);
        $title_array = preg_split("/\s+/", $title);

        $body = implode(" ", $body_array);
        $title = implode(" ", $title_array);
        //Current date and time
        $date_added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        //Get username
        $added_by = $this->user_obj->getUsername();

        //If user is on own profile, user_to is 'none'
        if($user_to == $added_by) {
            $user_to = "none";
        }

        //insert post 
        $query = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, body, added_by, user_to, image) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query->bind_param("sssss", $title, $body, $added_by, $user_to, $imageName);
        $query->execute();
        $returned_id = $query->insert_id;

        //Insert notification 

        if($user_to != 'none') {

            $notification = new Notification($this->con, $added_by);
            $notification->insertNotification($returned_id, $user_to, "profile_post");
        }

        //Update post count for user 
        $num_posts = $this->user_obj->getNumPosts();
        $num_posts++;

        $update_query = $this->con->prepare('UPDATE users SET num_posts = ? WHERE username = ?');
        $update_query->bind_param("is", $num_posts, $added_by );
        $update_query->execute();

        $stopWords = "i you are gay am a about above brandon tisson";

        $stopWords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $stopWords);

        $no_punctuation = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9] +/", "", $body);

        if (strpos($no_punctuation, "height") === false && strpos($no_punctuation, "width") 
            === false && strpos($no_punctuation, "http") === false) {

            $no_punctuation = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $no_punctuation);

            foreach ($stopWords as $value ) {

                foreach ($no_punctuation as $key => $value2) {

                    if (strtolower($value) == strtolower($value2) ) {

                        $no_punctuation[$key] = "";
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($no_punctuation as $value) {

                $this->calculateTrend(ucfirst($value));
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $returned_id;
}
```